# Show a layout on Pull of ActionBar/ToolBar item

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-actionbar-compat, android-toolbar

I want to show the layout on Pull of ActionBar/ToolBar items. This layout has to overlay ActionBar/ToolBar, in otherwords this layout has to visible on top of ActionBar/Toolbar.

This requirement is similar to Android's default Notification Drawer.

I have a ToolBar and a item on it. If I pull that item, a new layout has to come from Top with fixed height and this layout can be closed by tapping on that ToolBar item with pull effect.

I tried Umano's SlidingPanel couldn't succeed.

And I used [DialogPlus](https://github.com/orhanobut/dialogplus) library. I get closer to my requirement. Using DialogPlus it can be achieved on click of ToolBar item but pull effect is missing.

How can I show/hide a layout using pull effect?

[image]

Comment: How did you solve it?

Comment: sorry. I didn't solve

Answer (score 1):

here is a simple xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#0061C2"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"
        app:theme="@style/Toolbar"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/myLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:background="#ffff7100"
        android:visibility="gone">

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**The toolbar is behinf "myLayout" , so if "myLayout" is visible it will hide the toolbar**
in your java , when clicking on that item

```
  (findViewById(R.id.myLayout).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

and a layout will be displayed, you will get an animation because i'm using

```
android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
```

add the same item at the bottom of myLayout and add this as its onClickListener

```
(findViewById(R.id.myLayout).setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

**You can do this using toolbar**

Answer (score 0):

To do things in response to a gesture implement gestureListener. For this case you can create an anonymous inner class or you can straight away implement the SimpleGestureListener and in onFling method you can code your logic for change of layout.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements 
    GestureDetector.OnGestureListener,
    GestureDetector.OnDoubleTapListener{

private GestureDetectorCompat mDetector; 

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

...
//other unimplemented methods..

@Override
public boolean onFling(MotionEvent event1, MotionEvent event2, 
        float velocityX, float velocityY) {
    //logic for layout change
    return true;
}
}
```

Comment: @DroidLearner did you find it useful?

Comment: This answer isn't useful. How do you compute what direction the fling is?